# Complexity of an iterative method?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, iteration

### **Problem:**

I want to implement the [Jacobi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method). It is similar to a fix point method:

```
Xn+1 = P Xn +Q

if X* verify X=PX +Q 

then if Xn converge then it converge to X*
```

let say I succeed in finding alpha <1 such that :

`||PX|| < alpha * ||X||` (usually alpha is the max of the eigen values of P but it doesn't matter here)

Then my method will converge.

### **Complexity**:

I would like to calculate the complexity of such an algorithm. let say I want ||Xn-X*|| to be less than epsilon.
for one given alpha I can calculate n such that the above inequality is verified. But in my case I can prove such alpha exist but I don't have his value.

Are there methods for calculating complexity for such iterative methods without knowing explicitely alpha ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any more information: No.

In order for there to be a bound you need to prove *uniform* convergence of the process over all alpha values. But that convergence doesn't exist (unless you have a stronger condition, for example `alpha < 0.9`

Not sure why you can't generate a constructive process to find an upper bound < 1 on alpha if you can prove existence. Mostly proving that a method converges is simply finding a relevant norm in which the matrix norm < 1 *by explicitly finding its value*.

In any case, here's a proof by contradiction.

**PROOF**

Let `epsilon > 0`.
Let's assume that we can bound the number of iterations by some `f(x)` where `f: R+ --> N`.
I.e. If `e_n = ||Xn - X*||` we assume that for all `n > f(epsilon). e_n < epsilon`.

We will show that there exists a valid alpha and an `N` such that `N > f(epsilon). e_N > epsilon`.

The key observation is to note that our function `f` is independent of alpha's value. We assume the existence of some upper bound on the iterative process without knowing alpha's value, only that `alpha<1`. So it is enough to find an alpha satisfying that condition that breaks the initial assumptions on `f` to reach our desired contradiction.

This point is delicate, since the existence of a valid bound `f` *is* actually dependant on alpha since the assumption is that it bounds the iterations which are based on the matrix on which alpha is "defined". Although since alpha itself is unknown we must prove that `f` is valid for **all** values of alpha, and that's where we move from normal convergence to uniform convergence.

We have chosen our epsilon, and we take `N = f(epsilon)+1`.
According to our assumption `e_N < epsilon`, so let's simply take `alpha = (2*epsilon/e_0) ^ 1/2N` assuming `2*epsilon/e_0 < 1` otherwise we could substitute epsilon with any value < 1.

```
e_n+1 = || X(n+1) - X* ||
      = || PXn + Q - PX* - Q ||
      = || P(Xn - X*) ||
      <= ||P|| ||Xn-X*||
      = ||P|| e_n
```

As I stated, given no extra information it's easy to construct `P` such that the inequality above is actual equality. For example `P = I*k` yields equality for all real `k`. Therefore there exist `P` such that `e_n+1 = ||P|| e_n = ... = ||P||^(n+1) * e_0`

Our last observation is that even if `||PX|| < alpha * ||X||` there may exist `X` such that: `||PX|| > alpha^2 * ||X||`.
For example if `P = I * alpha` we know that `alpha<1` and the aforementioned is true for all `X`. (Again, since there is no other information on `P`, the fact that there may exist such `X` is enough.)

If we plug in our `alpha` in we conclude that the following is possible:

```
e_N = ||P||^N * e_0
    > (alpha^2)^N * e_0
    = alpha^2N * e_0
    = 2*epsilon  // since alpha = (2*epsilon/e_0) ^ 1/2N
    > epsilon
    > e_N // since we assumed we had a bound, and e_N < epsilon
```

A number cannot be larger than itself.

QED.

Comment: Thanks I kind of realised it would be impossible to do without more condition on alpha, I will try to find a stronger condition on alpha.